# Uploading data with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am uploading a lot of data to a database using entity framework. I have a lot of different entities with relations between them. 
My problem is that sometimes the object I'm uploading might already be in the database, but when I look up that object and find it, I can't add it to my locally made entities, because they belong to different contexts.

For example, I have the entities Sailor and Booze, which have a relation.  I have a new sailor Ackbar and I know his favourite booze is rum and I want to persist this to the database.
I make a new sailor and set its name to Ackbar. Then I look up to see if Booze has an entry called rum. If it has, I try to add it to Ackbar. When I do this, EF complains that the new sailor and the booze from the database belong to different contexts.
If I try to attach sailor to the context, it complains that sailor has a null entity key.

How can I build all these relations without saving anything to the database before I'm done editing the relationships?

Comment: Try using one `context` instance is all I can suggest without a single line of code.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of code, I can't really put anything online.

The reason for not using one context is that I've that you are supposed to only use the context for short periods of time. During the context I will be reading an entire word document and unloading data from it..

Comment: It's ok to use the same `Context` for this operation. You can recycle the `context` after each `SaveChanges` if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you alter your code to use the same `Context` for reading and writing. Having multiple contexts for a single transaction is not a better option than having a `Context` that's alive for a few minutes.